# What are the Esperanto pangrams?

Tags: typography

I am looking for pangrams to use as sample text when choosing fonts for text in Esperanto. A pangram is a sentence that contains every letter of the alphabet, such as "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" in English.

Answer (score 14):

My favourite is this one because it is easy to remember and it sounds like a natural sentence:

> Laŭ Ludoviko Zamenhof bongustas freŝa ĉeĥa manĝaĵo kun spicoj.

You can even get it on a [t-shirt](http://tutmonde.org/produktoj/spicoj-malgranda).

If you just want to test the Esperanto letters then this single word is also very common:

> eĥoŝanĝoĉiuĵaŭde

[Vikipedio has a list](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%88iulitera%C4%B5o#Ekzemploj) of others of varying lengths.

Answer (score 8):

I have only ever seen one, but I have actually seen it printed on t-shirts, which makes me belive it is the most well known:

> Laŭ Ludoviko Zamenhof bongustas freŝa ĉeĥa manĝaĵo kun spicoj.

"According to Ludwig Zamenhof, fresh Czech food with spices tastes good".